# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - stack trace points to closing brace of random if statement

Tags: razor, blazor-webassembly

Visual Studio is not giving me a detailed or useful error message, and is only pointing to line 160 which I have marked with "[[THE ERROR APPEARS HERE!]]". This is an extract of code from my index.razor file:

```
@if (gameState == GameState.GetAIImage)
{
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageSrc))
    {
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img src="@ImageSrc" style="width:600px;" />
        </div>
        <br>

    }

    <EditForm EditContext="@promptEditContext" OnValidSubmit="@GetAIImage">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            @if (promptEditContext != null && promptEditContext.GetValidationMessages().Any())
            {
                var messages = string.Join(", ", promptEditContext.GetValidationMessages());
                <div class="alert alert-danger">@messages</div>
            }


            <div class="input-group">
                <InputText placeholder="Describe this image..." class="form-control" @bind-Value="promptModel.Prompt" size="100" />
                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(promptModel.Prompt))
                {
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn bg-transparent" type="button" style="margin-left: -40px; z-index: 100;" @onclick="ClearPrompt" title="Clear input">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                } [[THE ERROR APPEARS HERE!]]

            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="buttons" class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="gap:10px;">
                <span><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@isGenerating"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i> Generate</button></span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="GetRandomPhoto" disabled="@isGenerating"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrows-rotate"></i> Try another photo</button></span>
                <span><button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="SubmitGenerated" disabled="@(isGenerating || !ImageSrc.Contains("base64"))"><i class="fa-solid fa-flag-checkered"></i> Submit!</button></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>

}
```

I am expecting to be able to use conditionals as I was using them before. I do conditionals the exact same way in other areas of the page and they work just fine, so what's wrong with how I do it here?

The full error is as follows:

````
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BlazorAIArt.Client.Pages.Index.<BuildRenderTree>b__65_13(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2) in E:\Visual Studio Projects\BlazorAIArt\BlazorAIArt\Client\Pages\Index.razor:line 160
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValue`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)```
````

Comment: I would say that your promptModel is null and it points at the end of the if statement because it considers it one statement.

Comment: I tried adding a null check just before:

```csharp
@if (promptModel != null)
    {
     @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(promptModel.Prompt))
     {
      <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn bg-transparent" type="button" style="margin-left: -40px; z-index: 100;" @onclick="ClearPrompt" title="Clear input">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
       </button>

      </div>
     }
    }```

however, I am still getting the same error. thanks for the idea tho!

Comment: You have `@bind-Value="promptModel.Prompt` just before that. It's a std C# issue, validate that in all `X.Y` expressions `X` is not null.

Comment: Easiest way is to make sure you always have a valid `promptModel`.

Comment: How would I check for a valid promptModel here? I already validate in the `OnSubmit` / `OnValidSubmit` section

also, quick note: I've spent a while adding many extra null checks to the code to make sure *absolutely nothing* is null, and it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a variable I was accessing was not initialized properly.
The original code was:

```cs
private string ImageSrc { get; set; } = default!;
```

but it should instead be

```cs
private string ImageSrc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

as `default!` doesn't work properly for strings.
In summary, this was a skill issue and I am closing this thread in shame.

Comment: `default` works just fine for strings. Using `""` (String.Empty) is just suppressing symptoms and warnings. It should have been `string? ImageSrc { get; set; }`